# Datetime format date received is in different format in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, datejs

I have a table which contains a column named DOB whose data type is DATETIME.The problem is that created_at is also a datetime but its data received through JSON is in this format

```
"created_at":"2013-02-02 11:57:42",
"dob":"2013-02-18T18:30:00Z"
```

Both the dates are in different format but both of them has datetime data type.
Now I'm using [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)

to format the date which will not parse DOB format it can only parse created_at format.

What should I do now ?

Here's what I'm doing to parse through datejs

```
        if(value.dob != null){
            alert(value.dob);
            d1 = Date.parse(value.dob);
            alert(d1);
            dob = d1.toString("M-d-yyyy");

        }
```

And I'm getting this error on console:

```
: d1 is null
[Break On This Error]   

dob = d1.toString("M-d-yyyy");
```

My controller:

```
  def get_oi_report_contact
       @contactlist = CaseOiReportMap.select("rc.*").where("case_oi_report_maps.oireport_identifier = ?",identifier)
       .joins("LEFT JOIN case_oi_report_contacts_maps cm on cm.case_oi_report_map_id = case_oi_report_maps.id")
       .joins("LEFT JOIN oi_report_contacts rc on rc.id = cm.oi_report_contact_id ")
       respond_to do |format|
          format.json { render :json => @contactlist.to_json }
       end

  end
```

I have also used monkey patch:

```
class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
    def as_json(options = {})
        strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    end
end
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strftime` to format the time string http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime

Comment: It has to be through Javascript as I'm using ajax and JSON to receive data.

Comment: i think i misunderstood your requirements.  are you trying to parse "dob":"2013-02-18T18:30:00Z" using datejs?  how are you setting dob if this is the case?

Comment: Sorry I didn't got you..do You mean How I'm inserting? or dob column data type? One thing DOB datatype is DATETIME and it is stored in this format 2013-02-02 19:09:14

Comment: i get that, but where did you get "dob":"2013-02-18T18:30:00Z"?  is that a json response from the server that you are trying to parse with datejs? if it is, show the code in the controller that sends this json.

Comment: can you try the option described in this page? http://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/to_json

Comment: I have also Implemented monkey patch but it doesn't seem to work.Please check my edited question